# Steam doesn't work after update to Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: drivers, steam, opengl

I updated from Ubuntu 18.04 to 19.04 today but to my surprise steam stopped working after the update.

Running steam from the command line gives the following error:

```
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  3 (X_GLXCreateContext)
Value in failed request:  0x0
Serial number of failed request:  51
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
Serial number of failed request:  52
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
```

since the problem wasn't solved after a reboot, i googled and found that my opengl driver was broken.

output of glxinfo:

```
name of display: :0
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  152 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  63
  Current serial number in output stream:  62
```

I did the following to try solve this:

```
sudo apt install mesa-utils
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Now, output of `glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"`is: (glxgears works too)

```
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 430.26
```

But Steam is still giving the exact same error. How should i solve this ?

Any help would be much appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just remove `~/.steam` and `~/Steam` directory and run steam again

Comment: one of the first things i tried, doesn't work, steam updates again but doesn't go beyond that.

Answer (score 7):

Steam uses 32 bits libraries (i386) and you don't have them. In my case, I have nvidia 390 driver, so I installed *libnvidia-gl-390:i386* package and it solved the problem. In your case, since you have nvidia 430 driver, this should solve the issue for you:

```
sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-430:i386
```

Comment: I had the same issue with driver version 440 and confirmed that works for me when using `gl-440:i386`

Answer (score 2):

NOTE that in my case this was related the CUDA-problem

CUDA repos has alternative versions for Nvidia drivers and these dont offer i386 versions so it created a dependency problem.

The solution is to disable CUDA repos.

Please check here:
[NVIDIA 440.64 32-bit libraries package breaks 64-bit driver package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1222020/nvidia-440-64-32-bit-libraries-package-breaks-64-bit-driver-package)

Now the problem is when you want to have CUDA and Steam at the same time.
Thats a different problem.

Comment: How do you solve that problem?  I can't disable cuda in order to install steam.

Comment: Disable cuda repos? how ?!