# libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, playonlinux, opengl

Trying to install GTA San Andreas over PlayOnLinux but I got the error:

```
0009:err:wgl:init_opengl Failed to load libGL: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No>  such file or directory
0009:err:wgl:init_opengl OpenGL support is disabled.
```

Already tried to install the libGL i386 in dozens of way but I always got the "dependency hell"

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

I got the dependency errors:

```
libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 is already the newest version (20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Depends: libgl1:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: libglx-mesa0:i386 but it is not going to be installed
```

My distro:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I go no idea how to solve this dependency errors to enable the OpenGL support for playing the GTA San Andreas, which is a 32 bits game, in my Ubuntu Mate 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem for me. And I solved it using two steps.

first, I try to find where is the `libGL`. Using `locate libGL.so`, find that:

```
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
/snap/scrcpy/269/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/snap/scrcpy/269/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
/snap/scrcpy/274/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/snap/scrcpy/274/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
/snap/wine-platform-runtime/212/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/snap/wine-platform-runtime/212/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
/snap/wine-platform-runtime/212/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/snap/wine-platform-runtime/212/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
/snap/wine-platform-runtime/216/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/snap/wine-platform-runtime/216/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
/snap/wine-platform-runtime/216/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/snap/wine-platform-runtime/216/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0
```

And I link the `libGL.so` and other opengl libraries from `/snap/wine-platform-runtime/216/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` to `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`. Maybe you should install wine-platform-runtime by snap.

do this:

```bsh
sudo ln -s /snap/wine-platform-runtime/216/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
sudo ln -s /snap/wine-platform-runtime/216/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.0.0
sudo ln -s /snap/wine-platform-runtime/216/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0
sudo ln -s /snap/wine-platform-runtime/216/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0.0.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0.0.0
sudo ln -s /snap/wine-platform-runtime/216/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0
sudo ln -s /snap/wine-platform-runtime/216/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0.0.0 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0.0.0
```

It still not worked, and a new problem happened. (but the step is necessary for me.)

```
err:wgl:X11DRV_WineGL_InitOpenglInfo couldn't initialize OpenGL, expect problems
```

And then, the second step:

My nvidia driver version is 460. take 460 for example.

```bsh
sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-460:i386
```

And when installing it, if it tells you `nvidia-driver-460` will be removed, it is not good, and you should make `nvidia-driver-460` and `libnvidia-gl-460:i386` exist at the same time. And I solved it by removing cuda repo and reinstall `libnvidia-gl-460:i386` and `nvidia-driver-460`.(details? see: [NVIDIA 440.64 32-bit libraries package breaks 64-bit driver package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1222020/nvidia-440-64-32-bit-libraries-package-breaks-64-bit-driver-package), and thanks for it.)

And my `dpkg -l|grep nvidia`:

```
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-460:amd64                      460.73.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-460                          460.73.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                       all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-460:amd64                   460.73.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-460:i386                    460.73.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                       i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-460:amd64                    460.73.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-460:i386                     460.73.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                       i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-460:amd64                    460.73.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                       amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-460:i386                     460.73.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                       i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-460:amd64                     460.73.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                       amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-460:amd64                      460.73.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-460:amd64                        460.73.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-460:i386                         460.73.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                       i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-460:amd64                      460.73.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-460                      460.73.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-460                               460.73.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-460                             460.73.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-460                      460.73.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                       amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-460                      460.73.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                                  0.8.16~0.18.04.1                                 all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                               450.51.05-0ubuntu1                               amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-460                              460.73.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460                 460.73.01-0ubuntu0.18.04.2                       amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Hope it will help you.